# start OSGI bundle programmatically in apache servicemix

Tags: java, web-services, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

Servicemix expert. I need some guidance. Below is my problem scenario.

A web application(webapp1) is running in tomcat container and on same machine servicemix(v4.5.3) is executing. 
I have already deployed web service(ws1) on servicemix using apache cxf . I hit the web service(ws1) from my webapplication(webapp1). It's working fine. Now, my problem is I want to  start another already installed bundle(simple java application) on servicemix programmatically. I want to write business logic to start bundle in web service(ws1) so that when I hit webservice(ws1), it starts that bundle.

Need some suggestion please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Web Service bundle deployed to ServiceMix is using Spring configuration, you can get access to a BundleContext simply by adding a property (and setter method) to any bean:

```
<property name="bundleContext" ref="bundleContext" />
```

The [BundleContext](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) gives you access to a range of things, in your instance use either the `getBundle` or `getBundles` method to get the required Bundle object, then issue start/stop etc.

Comment: I have already done that, but the problem is after getting list of bundles using bundleContext.getBundles(), how to get particular bundle without knowing it's id and location. I want to get bundle using it's name. Is it possible? I know that each bundle have unique id by which we can get bundle.

Comment: Sure, you can use either or both of these depending on your manifest entries: `bundle.getSymbolicName()` and `bundle.getHeaders().get(org.osgi.framework.Constants.BUNDLE_NAME)`.